# How to get sodium from sodium aluminate?

Tags: redox, home-experiment

The [sodium aluminate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_aluminate) is formed when aluminium or aluminium hydroxide reacts with water solution of lye. After drying the water you'll end up with white crystals - sodium aluminate.

I was wondering if it's possible to get pure Na out of this compound - by heating or a redox reaction.

Comment: Generally, it's quite difficult to get elemental alkali metals from their compounds. If your aim is to get sodium, you should consider reacting sodium hydroxide with magnesium (violent reaction) to form magnesium hydroxide and sodium.

Comment: @AnonymousShadow I heard of that reaction. I also saw it done with aluminum as well. The problem is that it requires you to grind sodium hydroxide. When you do so, it's gyroscopic properties take on so fast that it's immediately wet and the reaction is not quite possible.